# Swirling circle for 5 seconds each time returning to Design view

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, delay

I recently got a new computer and had to install Visual Studio again.  I am currently making a game using C# in Visual Studio 2019, but I notice something rather unusual whilst I am making my application.. Whenever I run my application, even if its just a simple blank form, it goes to normal run view, but then when I click the red stop button to stop debugging, and return back to design view, the familiar blue swirling circle cursor appears for approx 5-7 seconds before the normal cursor returns.

This happens every time I return to design view, from run-time view.  I have to wait these 5 seconds or so, before I can carry on coding, and this adds up to a lot of time, especially when I am going in and out of design view about a hundred times a day!

Any ideas, what is causing this constant swirling circle, is there a setting that needs turning on... or off??

Regarding my laptop I have got 8GB RAM and 2Ghz CPU.

Any info appreciated,
Thanks

Mark.

Comment: This isn't strictly a StackOverflow issue, but I believe that your system is marginal on Visual Studio minimum system requirements https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements

Comment: OK thanks for the response Chris.